# How do I add a date time attribute in rspec?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

I have a test suite that continues to fail because of an unknown attribute error. The unknown attribute is datetime. Below is my schema file:

```
create_table "posts", force: true do |t|
  t.string   "title",             null: false
  t.text     "body",              null: false
  t.datetime "date_created",      null: false
  t.integer  "author_id",         null: false
  t.datetime "created_at"
  t.datetime "updated_at"
  t.integer  "interest_group_id", null: false
  t.integer  "comments_count"
end
```

Here is a snippet from my rspec file:

```
let(:post){Post.new(body: 'hello', title: 'Hello, 
by the Beatles', author: author, interest_group: interest_group, 
date_created: ?????)}
```

My question is simple what do I place in the date_created field? Its looking for a value that is datetime specific but what does that look like? I've tried putting '2012-3-13' as an example but it fails due to the value being a string? Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about this?

```
let(:post){Post.new(body: 'hello', title: 'Hello, 
by the Beatles', author: author, interest_group: interest_group, 
date_created: DateTime.parse('2012-3-13'))}
```